# Going to Edit mode still shows mesh in object mode

Tags: edit-mode

I'm want to edit some vertices... but when I go to EDIT MODE it still shows mesh in object mode.

[image]

Comment: Edit your (armature) modifier settings, you'll probably have to disable the poly-icon.

Comment: @Leander I'm already in modifier area... https://i.imgur.com/e1P36qV.png I can't find the "POLY-ICON" you are saying.

Comment: [Show in edit mode icon](https://imgur.com/a/EZOUGfo)